# lapack complains about libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, lapack, armadillo

I am trying to write a program that uses armadillo in Visual Studio. I downloaded Prebuilt libraries for lapack and blas from http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/. I also downloaded MinGW and added C:/MinGW/bin to my System PATH. C:/MinGW/bin has libgfortran-3.dll and libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll which are what the lapack documentation states is needed. However, when I attempt to run my program I get a runtime error stating that the program can't run because libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing. This dll does not come with MinGW and I tried downloading multiple versions. How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: try adding "path of static lib"   and its "static  lib" in "configuration properties->linker->general->additional library directories" and "configuration properties->linker->input->additional dependencies"

Comment: Do you mean for liblapack.lib and libblas.lib? If so, I did this already. Or do you mean with other static libs?

Comment: Static lib associated to the dll.... that is causing problem....do you have any

Comment: I don't know of any static libs associated with libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll

Comment: Ok.... did you place the dll in rt place? Or try to put it in system dirrctory

Comment: The dll is missing. That's the problem I am having. It's not in the bin folder after I install MinGW.

Comment: oho ok,,,. got it.....I thought you have a DLL already..

Answer (score 0):

The MinGW-w64 project have something called "personal builds". One of them is "sjlj". The library is built using a gcc compiler from this personal build.

Assuming that it was used the current latest version (6.3.0) and win32 threads the you can find the toolchain binaries [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/6.3.0/threads-win32/sjlj/). If not, you can check some other versions.

You can either extract the dll you need or extract it and add it to your system path.